# Infinite While loops in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, math, infinite

I have the following program which should count the number of years it should take a population to grow to the desired size. Whenever I run this I get an infinite loop. Can someone help me identify my error?

```
def pop_growth(start, percent, desired)      
  year_count = 0
  while start <= desired    
    year_count += 1
    start = start + (start * (percent / 100))
  end
  return year_count
end
```

Comment: Assuming the argument `percent` is an integer less than 100, `percent/100` will be zero (integer division, remember?). You need `percent/100.0` to return a float such as 0.50. Incidentally, considering your method of  calculation, this question has nothing to do with `inject`, so you might remove that from the title.

Comment: @CarySwoveland as I read your comment I felt myself obliged to provide an answer based on `inject` :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that you are trying with Integers (instead floats), so you are losing precision try this

```
def pop_growth(start, percent, desired)      
  year_count = 0
  while start <= desired    
    year_count += 1
    start = start + (start * (percent.to_f / 100))
  end
  return year_count
end
```

and let me know if it works for you. if not can you send me your start, percent and desired values?

Answer (score 2):

The proper answer is given by Horacio, let me rewrite this in idiomatic ruby:

```
def pop_growth start, percent, desired
  (0..Float::INFINITY).inject(start) do |memo, years|
    break years if memo > desired    
    memo *= (1.0 + percent / 100.0)
  end
end
```

or, with infinite loop:

```
def pop_growth start, percent, desired
  loop.each_with_object(years: 0, count: start) do |_, memo|
    break memo[:years] if memo[:count] > desired    
    memo[:years] += 1
    memo[:count] *= (1.0 + percent / 100.0)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Three ways.

**#1 Solve equation**

Solve `desired = start * (1.0 + 0.01 * percent)**n` for `n`:

```
def pop_growth(start, percent, desired)      
  Math.log(desired.to_f/start)/Math.log(1.0 + percent/100.0)
end

years = pop_growth(100, 10, 200)
  #=> 7.272540897341713
```

`years.ceil #=> 8` if desired.

**#2 Compound until desire met**

```
def pop_growth(start, percent, desired)
  return 0 if start >= desired
  alpha = 1.0 + 0.01 * percent
  1.step.find { (start *= alpha) >= desired }
end

pop_growth 100, 10, 200
  #=> 8
```

**#3 Use recursion**

```
def pop_growth(start, percent, desired, years=0)
  return years if start >= desired
  pop_growth(start*(1.0+0.01*percent), percent, desired, years+1)
end

pop_growth 100, 10, 200
  #=> 8
```

Comment: Nice, but consider rounding the result, since `year_count` is to be integer, AFAIU.

Comment: @mudasobwa,it's not clear to me that an integer is required ("I'll pay off my mortgage in 8-1/2 years"), but I figured that should be `pop_growth(100, 10, 200).ceil #=> 8`, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.to_f` method to percent or divide by `100.0`, which will convert the integer into float.

```
start + (start * (percent / 100))
```

When you are dividing, you need at least one float number in order to return the exact division answer, else Ruby will round it down to nearest whole number, which in this case `percent / 100` will result in 0, assuming that the value in percent is less than 100. This will cause this statement `start + (start * (percent / 100))` to become `start = start + 0`, which is why you are seeing the infinite loop.